# Ошибка при загрузке gltf-файла в Reat-приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Создал отдельный компонент для загрузки и отображения сцены с gltf-объектом.
При попытке загрузить его с помощью `GLTFLoader`, падает ошибка:

[image: ошибка при загрузке gltf объекта]

#### Код загрузки gltf-объекта:

```js
setObj = () => {
        this.loader = new GLTFLoader();
        this.loader.load(obj, gltf => {
            this.mesh = gltf.scene;
            this.mesh.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
            this.mesh.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            this.mesh.position.set(0, -100, 0);
            this.scene.add(this.mesh);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Простое любопытство: а есть уверенность в том, что `this.mesh.children[0]` - это меш?

Comment: @prisoner849 ага :) решил переписать проект с нативного js на react. на нативном gltf работал отлично

Comment: @prisoner849 причина ошибки в том, что он ссылается на `http://localhost:3000/static/media/textures/Material_0.001_baseColor.jpeg`, а ее нет.